# Super slow cd into SSHFS mounted folder in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, unix, sshfs

I have an SSHFS mounted folder and it's working very well, except that when I try to `cd` into it from the terminal it lags for about 30s. Also, `ls -al` lists all the files but then lags for the same 30s before giving back the prompt. Viewing the folder in finder works normally with no delays. Opening and reading files with other programs (vi and macvim, for example) have no delays.

Everything works perfectly quickly and normally when I switch to root and run the same commands. When I SSH into the machine where the original folder is located, I can `ls` and `cd` to the folder with no problems.

When I run `sudo dtruss su MYUSERNAME ls -al` or `sudo dtruss su MYUSERNAME cd FOLDERPATH` I get a whole bunch of output, and then it hangs after giving me:

```
kevent64(0x3, 0x7FFF7F2BB730, 0x1)       = -1 Err#4
```

Just wondering how I can get rid of this delay, or what's really going on. I'm not sure what the kevent64 error is, and can't find much on it. Any thoughts? Hope someone can help, and thanks in advance!

UPDATE: actually I've just noticed that opening a file, for example with vi or macvim, opens the file and then lags in the background...